# как повернуть матрицу на javascript в игре тетрис?

Tags: javascript, html, css

уже долго сижу и не могу понять как сделать поворот матрицы. Прошу помощи. код с поворотом писать в функцию rotate. Заранее спасибо.

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Тетрис</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- рисуем поле для игры -->
  <canvas width="320" height="640" id="game"></canvas>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
*{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

canvas {
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('game');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
const grid = 32;

//послед.фигур
let tetrominoSequence = [];

//поле
let playfield = [];

//заполняем фигурами
for (let row = -2; row < 20; row++) {
  playfield[row] = [];

  for (let col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
    playfield[row][col] = 0;
  }
}

//сами фигуры в виде двумерного массива
const tetrominos = {
  'I': [
    [0,0,0,0],
    [1,1,1,1],
    [0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0],
  ],
  'J': [
    [1,0,0],
    [1,1,1],
    [0,0,0],
  ],
  'L': [
    [0,0,1],
    [1,1,1],
    [0,0,0],
  ],

  //квадрат если ч0
  'O': [
    [1,1],
    [1,1],
  ],
  'S': [
    [0,1,1],
    [1,1,0],
    [0,0,0],
  ],
  'Z': [
    [1,1,0],
    [0,1,1],
    [0,0,0],
  ],
  'T': [
    [0,1,0],
    [1,1,1],
    [0,0,0],
  ]
};

//цвет для фигур
//рандомный, кста
const colors = {
  'I': '#' + (Math.random().toString(16) + '000000').substring(2,8).toUpperCase(),
  'O': '#' + (Math.random().toString(16) + '000000').substring(2,8).toUpperCase(),
  'T': '#' + (Math.random().toString(16) + '000000').substring(2,8).toUpperCase(),
  'S': '#' + (Math.random().toString(16) + '000000').substring(2,8).toUpperCase(),
  'Z': '#' + (Math.random().toString(16) + '000000').substring(2,8).toUpperCase(),
  'J': '#' + (Math.random().toString(16) + '000000').substring(2,8).toUpperCase(),
  'L': '#' + (Math.random().toString(16) + '000000').substring(2,8).toUpperCase()
};

let count = 0;
// фигура, которая сейчас
let tetromino = getNextTetromino();
//кадры
let rAF = null;
// обозначение конца игры
let gameOver = false;

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);

  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

//фигуры, которые будут в игре (их последовательность)
function generateSequence() {
  const sequence = ['I', 'J', 'L', 'O', 'S', 'T', 'Z'];

  while (sequence.length) {
    const rand = getRandomInt(0, sequence.length - 1);
    const name = sequence.splice(rand, 1)[0];
    tetrominoSequence.push(name);
  }
}

//получение фигуры
function getNextTetromino() {
  if (tetrominoSequence.length === 0) {
    generateSequence();
  }
  //отбираем у массива первую фигуру
  const name = tetrominoSequence.pop();
  //создание матрицы
  const matrix = tetrominos[name];
  const col = playfield[0].length / 2 - Math.ceil(matrix[0].length / 2);
  const row = name === 'I' ? -1 : -2;

  param_fig = {
    name: name,
    matrix: matrix,
    row: row,
    col: col
  };

  return param_fig;
}

console.log(param_fig);
// поворот фигуры

function rotate(param_fig){

}

// не вылазила за поле фигура
function isValidMove(matrix, cellRow, cellCol) {
  for (let row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++) {
      if (matrix[row][col] && (
          //если всё же за полем
          cellCol + col < 0 || cellCol + col >= playfield[0].length || cellRow + row >= playfield.length ||
          // при пересечении с другими фигурами
          playfield[cellRow + row][cellCol + col])
        ) {

        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}

// когда фигура окончательна встала на своё место
function placeTetromino() {
  for (let row = 0; row < tetromino.matrix.length; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < tetromino.matrix[row].length; col++) {
      if (tetromino.matrix[row][col]) {

        //если за поле, то игра закончена
        if (tetromino.row + row < 0) {
          return showGameOver();
        }
        // если не за полемы
        playfield[tetromino.row + row][tetromino.col + col] = tetromino.name;
      }
    }
  }

  // заполненные ряды очищены
  for (let row = playfield.length - 1; row >= 0; ) {
    // если ряд полон
    if (playfield[row].every(cell => !!cell)) {

      // очищаем его и опускаем всё вниз на одну клетку
      for (let r = row; r >= 0; r--) {
        for (let c = 0; c < playfield[r].length; c++) {
          playfield[r][c] = playfield[r-1][c];
        }
      }
    }
    else{
      row--;
    }
  }
  //получение следующей фигуры
  tetromino = getNextTetromino();
}

// Сам цикл с игрой
function loop() {
  //начало анимации
  rAF = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

  //отрисовка поля
  for (let row = 0; row < 20; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
      if (playfield[row][col]) {
        const name = playfield[row][col];
        context.fillStyle = colors[name];

        // рисуем всё на один пиксель меньше, чтобы получился эффект «в клетку»
        context.fillRect(col * grid, row * grid, grid-1, grid-1);
      }
    }
  }

  // отрисовка текущей фигуры
  if (tetromino){
    if (++count > 35) {
      tetromino.row++;
      count = 0;

      // при окончании движение
      //проверка можно ли удалить строку
      if (!isValidMove(tetromino.matrix, tetromino.row, tetromino.col)) {
        tetromino.row--;
        placeTetromino();
      }
    }

    //для того, давать цвет фигуры
    context.fillStyle = colors[tetromino.name];

    // отрисовка фигуры
    for (let row = 0; row < tetromino.matrix.length; row++) {
      for (let col = 0; col < tetromino.matrix[row].length; col++) {
        if (tetromino.matrix[row][col]) {

          // и снова рисуем на один пиксель меньше
          context.fillRect((tetromino.col + col) * grid, (tetromino.row + row) * grid, grid-1, grid-1);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// следим за нажатиями на клавиши
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {

  // стрелки влево и вправо
  if (e.which === 37 || e.which === 39) {
    const col = e.which === 37
      // если влево, то уменьшаем индекс в столбце, если вправо — увеличиваем
      ? tetromino.col - 1
      : tetromino.col + 1;

    // если так ходить можно, то запоминаем текущее положение
    if (isValidMove(tetromino.matrix, tetromino.row, col)) {
      tetromino.col = col;
    }
  }

  //кнопка для поворота
  if (e.which === 32) {
    rotate(param_fig);
  }

  // ускорение падения фигуры
  if(e.which === 40) {
    const row = tetromino.row + 1;
    if (!isValidMove(tetromino.matrix, row, tetromino.col)) {
      tetromino.row = row - 1;
      placeTetromino();

      return;
    }
    tetromino.row = row;
  }
});

rAF = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

Comment: [How to rotate a matrix in an array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171086/12593651)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function rt(param_fig){
let newMatrix = [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]];
let N = param_fig.matrix.length;
//для фигур
for(let y = 0; y < N; y++){
  for(let x = 0; x < N; x++){
    newMatrix[x][N-y-1] = param_fig.matrix[y][x];
  }
}
return newMatrix;}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]